# Haproxy public jenkin webhook only

Tags: bitbucket, haproxy

I want to allow Bitbucket access to my Jenkins callback `[Private IP]:[PORT]/bitbucket-hook` without public it entire port (/login, /jobs..) via haproxy.

Answer (score 0):

Found it, can use `path_end` to forward the request or use `reqirep` to modify when backend path is different with frontend path.

```
frontend http-in
  bind :444
  acl is-jenkin-callback path_end -i /bitbucket-hook
  use_backend jenkin-bitbucket-webhook if is-jenkin-callback
```